# Use of sample and seed in numpy

Tags: python, pandas, sample, pandas-loc

```
die = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

sum_of_dice = die.sample(n=2, replace=True).sum().loc[0]

print (sum_of_dice)
```

Can someone explain me what's `.sum().loc[0]` doing here?

Comment: Hi Rock Callahan. Can you update the tags in the question to include the language you're using? My best guess is Python. Also any library imports you are using would be great too.

Answer (score 1):

It's always useful to print the intermediate steps to get an idea.

`sum` calculates the sum of the dataframe for each column.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html

`loc` selects a group of rows/columns.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

`sum` returns a dataframe with one element, but as we need the sum in integer dtype not a dataframe, we use loc to get the first element.

```
import pandas as pd

die = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

sum_of_dice = die.sample(n=2, replace=True)

print(sum_of_dice)

sum_of_dice = sum_of_dice.sum()

print('---')
print (sum_of_dice)

sum_of_dice = sum_of_dice.loc[0]
print('---')
print (sum_of_dice)
```

```
  0
4  5
0  1
---
0    6
dtype: int64
---
6
```